# Ionic 5 : Webrtc remote video not displaying

Tags: ionic-framework, socket.io, webrtc, videocall

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppointmentService } from 'src/app/services/appointment.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-videocall',
  templateUrl: './videocall.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./videocall.page.scss'],
})
export class VideocallPage implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('localVideo', { static: true }) localVideo: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('remoteVideo', { static: true }) remoteVideo: ElementRef;
  consultationRoomId: any;
  callBtn: any;
  muteBtn: any;
  localStream: MediaStream;
  remoteStream: MediaStream;
  rtcPeerConnection: RTCPeerConnection;



  constructor(public socket: Socket, private toastCtrl: ToastController, private appoint: AppointmentService,
    private elRef: ElementRef) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.callBtn = document.getElementById("call");
    this.muteBtn = document.getElementById("mute");
    var endBtn = document.getElementById("end");
    var divConsultingRoom = document.getElementById("consultingRoom");

    var iceServers = {
      'iceServers': [
        { urls: 'stun:stun.services.mozilla.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun01.sipphone.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.ekiga.net' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.fwdnet.net' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.ideasip.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.iptel.org' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.schlund.de' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
        { urls: 'stun:stunserver.org' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.softjoys.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.voiparound.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.voxgratia.org' },
        { urls: 'stun:stun.xten.com' },
        {
          urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
          credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
          username: '28224511:1379330808'
        },
        {
          urls: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
          credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
          username: '28224511:1379330808'
        }
      ]
    }
    var streamConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };
    var isCaller;

    //this.consultationRoomId = this.appoint.getConsultationId();
    this.consultationRoomId = '1234';
    this.socket.connect();

    this.socket.on('created', (room) => {
      //debugger;
      alert('Starting consultation');
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then((stream) => {
        this.localStream = stream;
        this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
        isCaller = true;
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices', err);
      });
    });

    this.socket.on('joined', (room) => {
      alert('Joining consultation');
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(streamConstraints).then((stream) => {
        this.localStream = stream;
        this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
        this.socket.emit('ready', this.consultationRoomId);
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('An error ocurred when accessing media devices', err);
      });
    });

    this.socket.on('disconnect', (room) => {
      console.log('Doctor has ended the consultation>>>' + room);
    });

    this.socket.on('candidate', (event) => {
      var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
        sdpMLineIndex: event.label,
        candidate: event.candidate
      });
      this.rtcPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate);
    });

    this.socket.on('ready', () => {
      if (isCaller) {
        this.rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = this.onIceCandidate;
        this.rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = this.onAddStream;
        this.rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(this.localStream.getTracks()[0], this.localStream);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(this.localStream.getTracks()[1], this.localStream);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.createOffer()
          .then(sessionDescription => {
            this.rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
            this.socket.emit('offer', {
              type: 'offer',
              sdp: sessionDescription,
              room: this.consultationRoomId
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    });

    this.socket.on('offer', (event) => {
      if (!isCaller) {
        this.rtcPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(iceServers);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = this.onIceCandidate;
        this.rtcPeerConnection.ontrack = this.onAddStream;
        this.rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(this.localStream.getTracks()[0], this.localStream);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.addTrack(this.localStream.getTracks()[1], this.localStream);
        this.rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
        this.rtcPeerConnection.createAnswer()
          .then(sessionDescription => {
            this.rtcPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
            this.socket.emit('answer', {
              type: 'answer',
              sdp: sessionDescription,
              room: this.consultationRoomId
            });
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    });

    this.socket.on('answer', (event) => {
      console.log("on answer>>>>" + event);
      this.rtcPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(event));
    })

  }

  call() {
    //this.divConsultingRoom.style = "display: block;";
    this.socket.emit('create or join', this.consultationRoomId);
  }

  mute() {
    if (this.muteBtn.innerHTML == "Mute") {
      this.localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = false;
      this.muteBtn.innerHTML = "Unmute";
    }
    else {
      this.localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].enabled = true;
      this.muteBtn.innerHTML = "Mute";
    }
  }

  end() {
    this.socket.emit('disconnect', this.consultationRoomId);
  }

  onIceCandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      console.log('sending ice candidate');
      this.socket.emit('candidate', {
        type: 'candidate',
        label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
        id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
        candidate: event.candidate.candidate,
        room: this.consultationRoomId
      })
    }
  }

  onAddStream = (event) => {
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    this.remoteStream = event.streams[0];
  }

}
```

Below is the HTML page as well

```
<ion-content>
    <div id="consultingRoom">
        <video id="localVideo" #localVideo inline autoplay></video>
        <video id="remoteVideo" #remoteVideo inline autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <ion-button id="call" color="primary" (click)="call()">Call</ion-button>
    <ion-button id="mute" color="secondary" (click)="mute()">Mute</ion-button>
    <ion-button id="end" color="tertiary" (click)="end()">End</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

The event.streams[0] object in addStreamMethod shows the remote MediaStream with receiver's id but the remoteVideo element on front end is still blank.
The signalling server is a node socket server running on AWS EC2 instance.

Below is the debug for remote Media Stream

[RemoteMediaStream console debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPQ3G.png)

Below is the webrtc internals logs from Chrome

```
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverAdded
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverAdded
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
createOffer
options: {offerToReceiveVideo: -1, offerToReceiveAudio: -1, voiceActivityDetection: true, iceRestart: false}
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    negotiationneeded
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
createOfferOnSuccess
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
setLocalDescription
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverModified
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverModified
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
signalingstatechange
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    setLocalDescriptionOnSuccess
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icegatheringstatechange
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
setRemoteDescription
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverModified
9/3/2020, 4:39:00 PM    
transceiverModified
9/3/2020, 4:41:38 PM    
signalingstatechange
9/3/2020, 4:41:38 PM    setRemoteDescriptionOnSuccess
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icecandidateerror
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
icegatheringstatechange
complete
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
iceconnectionstatechange
checking
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
iceconnectionstatechange (legacy)
checking
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
connectionstatechange
connecting
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (host)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:39 PM    
addIceCandidate (srflx)
9/3/2020, 4:41:54 PM    
iceconnectionstatechange
disconnected
9/3/2020, 4:41:54 PM    
iceconnectionstatechange (legacy)
failed
9/3/2020, 4:41:54 PM    
connectionstatechange
failed
```

Currently I am only testing on browser, have not tested on Android and IOS yet
Please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: From logs it seems connection to ice server is breaking...kindly check whether firewall is blocking ice server and from terminal how packets are routed on turn servers

Comment: Hi @ShadowDroid we did try with firewall off on both local and remote machines but still the same error. We tried removing the TURN servers as the servers being used are not responding with relay. Please let me know what else can be done?

Comment: Have you got any solution ?

Comment: No solution found yet. Please can you assist?

Comment: Guys any help will be appreciated. Please assist.